# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: vb.net

```
sql = "insert into tbl_nurse(nurseid,nursename,deptname,dob,doj,qualification,salary)"
            sql = sql & "values('" & txtNurseid.Text & "','" & TxtNursename.Text & "','" & Cmbdept.Text & "',convert(date,'" & DateTimePicker1.Value & "',103),convert(date,'" & DateTimePicker2.Value & "',103),'" & Txtqualification.Text & "','" & txtsalary.Text & "')"
            conn.Execute(sql)
```

Comment: poor explanation !! ..

Comment: Use parameters. `DateTimePicker1.Value` is a `DateTime`. *Keep* it as a `datetime` throughout and don't force a conversion to string in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

You should use [sql-parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) to avoid [**sql-injection**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and to prevent from conversion issues like this.

Example presuming SQL-Server:

```
Const sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_nurse(nurseid,nursename,deptname,dob,doj,qualification,salary)" & vbCrLf & _
            "VALUES(@nurseid, @nursename, @deptname, @dob, @doj, @qualification, @salary)"
Using con = New SqlConnection("Insert Your Connection String Here")
    Using cmd = New SqlCommand(sql, con)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nurseid", txtNurseid.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nursename", TxtNursename.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@deptname", Cmbdept.Text)
        ' -- No conversion problems anymore because you pass a DateTime -- '
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", DateTimePicker1.Value)
        ' ... other parameters ... '
        con.Open()
        Dim affectedRecords As Int32 = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change like this ..

```
sql = "insert into tbl_nurse(nurseid,nursename,deptname,dob,doj,qualification,salary)"

sql = sql & " values('" & txtNurseid.Text & "','" & TxtNursename.Text & "','" & Cmbdept.Text & "',#" & format(DateTimePicker1.Value.Date) & "#,#" & format(DateTimePicker2.Value.Date) & "#,'" & Txtqualification.Text & "','" & txtsalary.Text & "')"

conn.Execute(sql)
```

As Tim Scmelter said .. you better use parameterize input

Answer (score 0):

Add Parameters as below and it works like charm

`cmnd.Parameters.Add("@date_time", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = datetime.Date;`

The original post is here:

https://www.codeproject.com/Answers/552202/Conversionplusfailedpluswhenplusconvertingplusdate#answer3